# De-Interlacing with Mediafoundation

Tags: video, directx, directshow, video-processing, ms-media-foundation

My problem is that I get interlaced uncompressed UYVY Frames and I need to deinterlace them.

My first guess was to do this with directshow and Dscaler, but I cant find a 64bit version of it (did I mention that the app is 64 bit?). I am also not able to compile it in 64 bit.

The next try would be media foundation. The EVR somehow deinterlace the frames. I would like to use this mechanism outside a renderer.

Has someone an idea?
(If there is any other idea how to deinterlace frames in another way, I would like to hear ;)

Comment: You can write your own MFT to deinterlace frames, or use a 3rd part MFT.

Comment: Is there no build in mechanism or available MFT which does it?  I don't know any third party MFT which does it.

Comment: You talk about Video Processor MFT. I can't test it because i don't have Win8/10, but it seems to do the trick. If you search, you will find commercial MFT...

Comment: I experimented with the vp. It's mentioned that it does de interlacing but I was not able to do so. I was able to put data in the MFT with process input. I set the incoming media type to interlacedormixed and the output to progressive. But the processoutput samples were still interlaced. I guess I am missing something. AFAIK Mediafoundation usually reacts immediately if something is set not right. I am open for any ideas.